# I'm running vim in the command line of Windows 10, but when editing I can't mouse scroll

Tags: windows, vim, scroll, cmd, mousewheel

Note that when I'm only using the command line without vim, I can scroll using the mouse wheel. However, when I open a file to edit, I also want to use the mouse wheel to scroll but it doesn't do anything. What can I do to make it scroll? Thanks!

Comment: Try reading `:help 'mouse'`.